# Counting words in column

Tags: t-sql, count, cpu-word

i must get count number the tag

```
<name></name>
```

in column.

```
<users><name>Tomek</name><name>Pawel</name><name>Krzysiek</name></users>
```

In this example data, queries should return 3.

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far.

Comment: use document.getElementsByTagName('name'). It will return an array get the length of that array

Comment: I try use SELECT LEN(@text) - LEN(REPLACE(@text, 'word', '')), but it good only with char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic sql solution:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Names NVARCHAR(1100))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
    ('<users><name>Tomek</name><name>Pawel</name><name>Krzysiek</name></users>'),
    ('<users><name>Tomek</name><name>Pawel</name><name>Krzysiek</name></users>'),
    ('<users><name>Tomek</name><name>Pawel</name><name>Krzysiek</name></users>')

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Sql = ''

SELECT
    @Sql = @Sql +

    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(Names,'</name>',''' as Names UNION ALL ')
            ,'<name>','SELECT ''')
        ,'</users>','')
    ,'<users>','')+CHAR(10)
FROM @Table

SET @Sql = LEFT(@Sql,LEN(@Sql)-11) 
SET @Sql = 'SELECT COUNT(Names) AS Names FROM (' + @Sql + ') as AllNames'
EXEC(@Sql)
```

Comment: My data is not var, it's column in table in database. I have a few row with column with sample xml

Comment: How about element <users><name = Tomek>Same text</name>

Comment: Okay i gave you a couple of samples and you can expand them to your need but im not going to do your whole work :)
Try to do the rest on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Using XPath you can easily implement the logic.

Example XPath for your scenario : count(/users/name)

Result : 3

[Test Here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/647943dc15e6e53695c8a4c73d031373)

Comment: how can i use this in t-sql

Answer (score 0):

if you work with xml data then try this variant

```
DECLARE @XMLdata XML = N'<users><name>Tomek</name><name>Pawel</name><name>Krzysiek</name></users>'
SELECT  COUNT(*) 
FROM @XMLdata.nodes('/users/name') col ( name )
```

This variant can be usefull when data storaged like a string (varchar)

```
--create temp table for testing
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Tags') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #Tags
CREATE TABLE #Tags
    (
      SampleText VARCHAR(1000)
    )
INSERT  INTO #Tags
        ( SampleText )
VALUES  ( '<users><name>Tomek</name><name>Pawel</name><name>Krzysiek</name></users>' ),
        ( '<users><name>Somik</name><name>Pawel</name><name>Krzysiek</name></users>' ),
        ( '<users><name>Krolik</name><name>Pawel</name><name>Krzysiek</name></users>' ),
        ( '<users><name>Domik</name><name>Pawel</name><name>Krzysiek</name></users>' ),
        ( '<users><name>Zontik</name><name>Pawel</name><name>Krzysiek</name></users>' );
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  recursive cte for split string
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   n = 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   n + 1
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    n <= 1000
             )
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- final query
        SELECT  COUNT(*) AS Cnt
        FROM    cte
                JOIN #Tags AS T ON n <= LEN(T.SampleText)
        WHERE   SUBSTRING(T.SampleText, n, 7) = '</name>'
OPTION  ( MAXRECURSION 1000 )
```

Comment: My data is not var, it's column in table in database. I have a few row with column with sample xml

Comment: @malymakar, you can do the same with a column, this is just an example

Comment: @malymakar recheck my post, variant with xml data type was added. also variant with string variable was updated to variant with table